# When do Kafka consumer retries happen?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

There is a retry feature on Kafka clients. I am struggling to find out when a retry happens. Would a retry happen if the connection to the broker in interrupted briefly? How about if the brokers were not reachable for 5 mins? Will the messages get delivered once the brokers are back up? Or does retry only happen on known scenarios to the kafka clients?

Comment: Sounds like you're asking about producer, but the title says consumer

Answer (score 2):

Kafka Producer consists of a pool of buffer space that holds records that haven't yet been transmitted to the server as well as a background I/O thread that is responsible for turning these batch records into requests and transmitting them to the cluster.

For example if records are sent faster than they can be delivered to the server the producer will block for `max.block.ms` after which it will throw an exception. Then client assumes batch is failed and will retry to send the batch based on `retries` config

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for my-test-topic-4 due to 30024 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
```

Suppose if the `retries` config is set to `3` and if all retries fails then the batch is lost

```
error: Failed to send message after 3 tries
```

**How about if the brokers were not reachable for 5 mins?**

If the broker is down and in mean time if retry is exhausted then you lost the data

Comment: but does the retry happen even when there is an connection interruption to the brokers? Or is that a instant exception?